# AJAX request fails to work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created a script that takes 2 post codes and returns the distance, if the distance is less than 4 miles it returns a success message, if it is over 4 miles it returns another message. It should also throw an error if the form field is empty.

I'd love to be able to return the data without refreshing the page but so far i can't seem to get the ajax request working, it just doesn't do a anything at all.

jQuery isn't my fortè i pieced this together by searching online.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#postcode-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

        var formData = {
            'destination': $('input#destination').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/postcode-finder.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                if (data.errors.destination) {
                    $('#destination-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.destination + '</div>');
                }

            } else {
                $('#postcode-form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
            }
        })

    });

});
```

**and the php code:**

$bakery       = 'DH12XL';
    $destination  = $_POST['destination'];

```
$errors       = [];
$result       = [];

if(empty($destination)) 
{
  $errors['postcode'] = 'Postcode is required';
}

if(!empty($errors)) 
{
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors'] = $errors;
} 
else
{
  $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$bakery&destinations=$destination&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=false&units=imperial";

  $google = @file_get_contents($url);
  $result = json_decode($google, true);

  $distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
  $many_miles = str_replace(' mi', '', $distance);

  if($many_miles > 4.0)
  {
    $data['message'] = 'Collection only for this postcode';
  }
  else 
  {
    $data['message'] = 'Good news, we deliver!';
  }
  $data['success'] = true;
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: They should make a checkbox for that question in the question editor. 'Before you post this question to SO, make sure you have... '

Comment: @JayBlanchard I wish I had a penny for every time I've had to post that bloody comment :)

Comment: They should just put those and a couple of others on auto-complete for the comment boxes @RoryMcCrossan :)

Comment: Yes but couldn't see anything.. funnily enough i've just tried it on Google chromes developer console and it seems random... it throws this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done' ...

but then other times its working 

http://www.sweettoothdelivery.co.uk/new/

Comment: You have an issue with the PHP. I've not got as far as an in-depth read of the jQuery but the first 2 lines will produce a parse error. If you want the default state of those variables to be '[]' then you'll need to enclose them in quote marks.

Comment: @LeeS `[]` is valid PHP from 5.4 onwards, it's a new way of saying `array()`

Comment: @bcmcfc Really?? Cripes .. I missed that. I stand corrected ... got to love SO for finding out something new every day. However - it may still be correct if the OP isn't on 5.4 I suppose

Comment: @LeeS yup. You're right on both counts - SO for learning stuff, and potentially that could be an issue if the OP's server is running 5.3.

Comment: $data = [1,2,3,4]; is the new array shorthand :) the PHP side of things is definitely working it returns the json as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery 1.4.4, which doesn't return [Promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) from `$.ajax` and therefore the `.done()` function isn't available.

You have two options:

Update jQuery (ensure you test anything else that's leaning on it if you do, though!)

Or use the success parameter instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'includes/postcode-finder.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true,
    success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).

Comment: Thank you i went with success: function() and it's working great now :)